# Tmpfs using up more than available RAM

Tags: 16.04, ram, tmpfs

I have 8GB RAM:

```
» cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        8096188 kB
```

But I am using way more than that just with the mounted `tmpfs`:

```
» sudo df -ha | grep tmpfs
tmpfs           791M  9,9M  781M   2% /run
tmpfs           3,9G   79M  3,8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3,9G  3,4M  3,9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /var/tmp
tmpfs           3,9G  1,4M  3,9G   1% /var/log
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /var/spool
tmpfs           791M   92K  791M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Obviously I am misunderstanding something here. Are the `tmpfs` sharing memory? Are they not maxing out? Will this be a problem if they start growing?

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271211/do-tmpfs-and-devtmpfs-share-the-same-memory-region/271235#271235)

*For all the tmpfs mounts, "Avail" is an artificial limit. The default size for tmpfs mounts is half your RAM. It can be adjusted at mount time. (man mount, scroll to tmpfs).*

Consider also that the limit of your `tmpfs` is half of your memmory (Physical memmory + SWAP)